# Date formatted differently in title versus window

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm running into an odd issue where the exact same date object is formatted differently in the title attribute versus an infoWindow.

In my Angular controller I set the date format like so:

```
var expirationDate = new Date(session.data.expiry_date);
```

Then within the marker object which I attached to the scope I pass this formatted date in:

```
var marker = {
  id: session.data.value,
  latitude: session.geolocation.location.latitude,
  longitude: session.geolocation.location.longitude,
  icon: icon,
  options: {title: 'Expiration: ' + expirationDate},
  expirationDate: expirationDate
};
```

In my `title` I see 'Fri Aug 07 2015 18:03:39 GMT-0400 ', yet in my infoWindow I see "2015-08-07T22:03:39.672Z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options: {title: 'Expiration: ' + expirationDate},
```

The `expirationDate` is implicitly converted to a string here before the concatenation occurs, and it is converted to a different string representation than if outputted directly as a Date object.

Try this in browser console:

```
>>> var d = new Date();
Date 2015-08-09T17:34:13.735Z
>>> d
Date 2015-08-09T17:34:13.735Z
>>> 'Expiration: ' + d
"Expiration: Sun Aug 09 2015 19:34:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks! I simply changed `expirationDate: expirationDate` to `expirationDate: expirationDate.toString()`.